# Ubuntu doesn't start X on boot

Tags: boot, xorg

After I upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS my system hasn't started X on boot. It's just a black screen, nothing else.

I can, however, `Ctrl+Alt+F1` into the shell, login, and command `startx`. The X server and desktop environment start without problems.

Comment: If you have an Nvidia card it can cause that.  OR a root partition that is too full.

Comment: I do have a Nvidia card. But weird cause before the upgrade I didn't have the problem. Yeah, my root partition is pretty full, but again, it has been before as well without problems.

Comment: I don't have the details in front of me. But from the command prompt you can update the drivers.  If that fails. Then purge nvidia and try the nouveau drivers.

Comment: I have the same issue in 22.04 and 22.10 with an nvidia card on 525 drivers